# How to break transposition cipher?

Tags: cryptanalysis, transposition-cipher

how to break a transposition cipher, especially a turning-grille-cipher?

For example:

$\begin{array}{rrrrrr}                                
T & E &R& E & W& E \\                                               
E & E&  & N & P & Q \\                                               
T& U & I & A& G & H \\      
Y & - & L & T &U & T \\    
S& L & E & S & E &   \\    
  & N& T & O& H&   \\                                             
\end{array}$

How would you break this cipher? Could you maybe give me a short step-by-step-explanation?

Please note: The spaces are there purposely and the text is in English.

Comment: Doesn't anyone has an idea?

Comment: Maybe try reading the corresponding chapter in [Cryptanalysis: a study of of ciphers and their solution](https://archive.org/details/cryptanalysis00hele/page/n3). It's quite old though, so I imagine one can do algorithmically better things at this point.